# Add Class to all table rows with any 2 classes and another style to all table rows with any 3 classes

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

Another YUI3 question.

I want to add a class(.two) to all table rows with 2 classes and another class(.three) to all table rows with 3 classes.

I found this piece JQuery of code from another question on here, I suspect this will work, but need to convert it to YUI3 and also allow for the two classes to be added, as well as changing the div to  somehow:

```
$(function(){
    var div = $('div[class*=" "]').filter(function(){
        var clsArray = $.trim(this.className.split(' ');
        return clsArray.size > 1;
    });
    div.css('background','yellow');
});
```

jsfiddle for above exmaple here:http://jsfiddle.net/udBZy/3/

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is what I have so far, but no luck :(

```
$(function() {

    YUI().use('node', function(Y) {

        var div = Y.all()('div[class*=" "]').filter(function(){

        var clsArray = Y.all().Lang.trim(this.className).split(' ');

        return clsArray.length > 1;

        });

        div.setStyle('background','yellow');

    });  

});
```

Comment: Perhaps this is not possible in YUI or too difficult? Any pure javascript options maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, via the YUI forums. This might help someone in the future:

```
YUI().use('node', function (Y) {
    var re = / {1,}/g;
    var div = Y.all('div[class *= " "]').each(function (n) {
        var numClasses =  Y.Lang.trim(n.get("className")).split(re).length;

        n.addClass("numClasses" + numClasses);
        n.setContent(n.getContent() + " found " + numClasses);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For any JQuery to YUI conversions, you have http://www.jsrosettastone.com/  and no, it is not difficult. Search the page for your JQuery methods and you'll find the equivalents.  You will need `Y.all()` and `node.addClass()`.

Comment: thanks, I have obviously looked at rosetta stone before i asked, and i am well aware that Y.all() and addClass() is needed, that's a no-brainer. this is not as easy as you might think, and if it was, why wont you just take the 30 seconds and write it for me? ;)